# Como converter bitcoin para real?

Tags: php

Galera, eu tenho o seguinte código que converte por exemplo **14.000** em reais para BTC que daria **1.07481682**, só que eu também queria fazer o caminho reverso desse cara, transformar os **1.07481682** em BTC para **14.000** reais. De que forma eu poderia fazer isso?

```
$url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$bitcoin_price = $data[30]["rate"];
$brl_value = 14000;
$value_bitcoin = round($brl_value / $bitcoin_price, 8);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($value_bitcoin);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que saber a cotação do bitcoin, acredito que seja a variável **$bitcoin_price** e multiplicar pela quantidade de bitcoins.

```
$total = $bitcoin_price * $amount_bitcoin
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, você literalmente salvou minha vida hahaha